# Loopback belongsTo relation with MongoDB giving Error 400

Tags: mongodb, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

In my MongoDB database, I have this data :

In a User collection :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2c725621691170792fbc3e"),
    "username" : "username",
    "email" : "test@gmail.com"
}
```

In a Content Collection :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2c7857b4f9e44a4d618bfd"),
    "title" : "Article title",
    "author" : ObjectId("5a2c725621691170792fbc3e")
}
```

So I've made 2 models in Loopback with a relation hasMany/belongsTo :

```
{
  "name": "user",
  ...
  "properties": {
    "username": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "contents": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "content",
      "foreignKey": "author"
    }
  }
}
```

Content has an author :

```
{
  "name": "content",
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "author": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": "author"
    }
  },
}
```

So that's great, Loopback give me those URLS :

- /users/{id}/contents to get Contents of an user, it's working fine
- /contents/{id}/author
  to get the Author of a content, but this one give me an error :

> 400 Key mismatch: content.author: function () { [native code] },
>   user.id: 5a2c725621691170792fbc3e

I can't figure out what's wrong, thanks !

Comment: _ "foreignKey": "author"_ can you point to this property

Comment: Did you sort this out? Having the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I set up an empty project and added models and relations like described and it works to get contents through user and user through content.

In you example data I see that *author* in *content* has a different *value* than *id* in *user*. Is that a typo in the question here or in the actual data?

> "_id" :    ObjectId("5a2c725621691170792fb**c3e**")
>
> "author" : ObjectId("5a2c7af721691170792fb**fd3**")

Comment: That's a typo, author and _id are the same in my actual data :)